# Problem with Time Evolving Block Decimation for small finite chains

Tags: computational-physics, quantum-mechanics

**Preliminary definitions:**

I have a code that uses TEBD (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-evolving_block_decimation) to perform time evolution of a given Matrix Product State (MPS), lets call it $|\Psi\rangle$. I am starting from a product state (Neél state) $|\uparrow,\downarrow,\uparrow,..,\downarrow\rangle$ for a chain of $L=10$ spins with spin $S=1/2$. I work with Open Boundary Conditions (OBC). The state is represented in the standard $\Gamma-\Lambda$ notation:
\begin{eqnarray}
|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{L}}\Lambda_{0}\Gamma_{1}\Lambda_{1}\Gamma_{2}\Lambda_{2}...\Lambda_{L-1}\Gamma_{L}\Lambda_{L}|\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{L}\rangle,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\Lambda_0=\Lambda_L=1$, and since the Neél state is a low-entangled state, initially all $\Lambda_{n=1,...,L-1}\equiv\text{diag}(1,0)$, i.e. I am fixing the initial bond dimension of ALL bonds to $\chi=2$. Therefore, initially, all $\Gamma,\Lambda$ are composed by $2\times 2$ matrices, and no loss of information on that initial state occurs.

The state is then time evolved (quenched) using the Heisenberg Hamiltonian:
\begin{eqnarray}
H=\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}\left(S_{i}^{x}S_{i+1}^{x}+S_{i}^{y}S_{i+1}^{y}\right) + \Delta\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}S_{i}^{z}S_{i+1}^{z}=\sum_{i=1}^{L-1}h_{i,i+1}.
\end{eqnarray}
The unitary evolution operator is decomposed using a 2nd order Trotter decomposition, acting on even and odd bonds to update the state after a single time step $dt$.

**Problem:**

As stated above, we start from a very low entangled state. After application of the unitary operator, and several $dt$ steps, I observe a growth of entanglement as expected. In particular, the $\Lambda_{n}$ matrices increase their dimension from $\chi=2$ to a dimension dependent on the bond position, i.e.:
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{dim}(\Lambda_{n})=d^{n},\hspace{10pt}\forall n\in[1,L-1].
\end{eqnarray}
However, after all dimensions reach these values, I observe no more growth in the $\Lambda_{n}$ dimensions, with a maximum dimension of $\chi=32$ at the middle bond ($\Lambda_{5}$), but fixed $\text{dim}(\Lambda_{1})=\text{dim}(\Lambda_{L-1})=2$, etc...

The problem is that way after this happens, I have no way to measure the discarded weight after a single SVD decomposition, as this always gives me 0, i.e., no eigenvalues of the $\Lambda$ matrices are discarded anymore. My feeling is that this is a wrong behaviour, but on the other hand, for a system of $L=10$ spin 1/2, the total amount of coefficients $c_{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{L}}$ is bounded to a total of $2^{L}=1024$ for $L=10$.

Is this normal in small systems approached by TEBD? Or on the contrary, should the bond dimensions of all $\Lambda_{n}$ keep growing and growing, in accordance with the entanglement growth featured by the quench? I am confused about this; my observables seem to reproduce some benchmarking results and I have observed that when $L$ is increased, I can reproduce the thermodynamic limit results. But why is this failing for the small chain case? How can we record the discarded weight after each dt step?